# I posted a not very good question. After learning more, I managed to make a better question. What should I do with the former?

Tags: support, question-quality, specific-question

Initially, I posted [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/45026/is-there-a-research-name-for-systems-that-steadily-grow-in-complexity-as-they-a?noredirect=1#comment92318_45026) question regarding evolutional computing. I knew it could be better phrased, but I couldn't figure out how, so I posted it that way. Later on, after an answer, some comments and more thought, I understand how I could narrow the question down and make it more precise. I posted a [follow-up](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/45042/what-are-examples-of-systems-that-once-run-long-enough-will-probably-develop-i) question and I believe it is better since it is much more clear what consists a right answer, and such right answer would be enough for myself to kickstart my search (a few examples of what I want would probably direct me to the right fields and papers).

Should I delete my previous question, close it, or leave it how it is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've had an answer which you found helpful, according to [this comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/45026/is-there-a-research-name-for-systems-that-steadily-grow-in-complexity-as-they-a#comment92323_45031). It wasn't the kind of answer you expected, and the question isn't what you'd meant to ask. Nonetheless, the question and answer now constitute a Q/A pair about computer science.

There's no reason for you to delete your question (and since it has an upvoted answer, you can't, anyway). Nobody has seen it fit to vote to close it so far. So there is no reason to remove this question.

Therefore that's a fine question. Maybe it isn't a stellar question, but that's ok, not every question is the best ever. Please leave this question on the site. As your question is a bit vague, you may want to edit it to be a closer match for the answer.

It's perfectly fine to ask a question, and then ask a follow-up question. Enlightenment doesn't come in a day.

Comment: Corollary: if that answer helped you, upvote and accept.

Answer (score 5):

It's up to you, but I don't think you need to delete the previous question.  As you say, it is a bit vague, but I don't think it's harmful or terrible.  One alternative to deleting the old question is to look at whether there are any ways of improving it; that would be a win-win for you and for the site.

One thing you could do that might improve the question is to provide additional context, about why you are asking and how you will use the answers.  Your meta question helps clarify that your goal is to kickstart your search, to try to identify the right fields and papers.  It might not hurt to add that.  The other thing I would suggest is to explain the motivation.  For instance, you ask about 'complexity'.  What is it about 'complexity' that and these examples that interest you?  Are you hoping to find insights about evolution, from the computer science literature?  Are you hoping this will somehow help deepen our understanding of some aspect of theoretical computer science?  Something else?  Understanding that might help readers identify fields that might be of interest to you -- especially as there are many different possible meanings and formalizations of the concept of 'complexity' floating around.

Also, if you can tell us what searching you've already done and what search phrases you've already tried, that would help.  For instance, have you spent some time on Google Scholar searching for likely phrases?  You mention "evolutional computing"; have you tried some searches on Google Scholar for things like "evolutional computing", "evolutionary computing", "evolution and computing", "computational evolution", etc.?  If you've tried that, then telling us what you've already tried might help readers avoid duplicating effort.  If you haven't tried that, then that'd be another step you could take that might improve your question ... and that incidentally also might help you formulate a more precise question.